# How can I cite multiple pages from the same site with no author listed in MLA?

Tags: academic-writing, citations, mla

I'm writing an MLA paper which in which I need to site 2 pages from https://www.merriam-webster.com. Here are what my citations look like in my works cited page:

> "dirigisme". Merriam-Webster Online, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dirigisme. Accessed 28 February 2020.
>
> "fascism". Merriam-Webster Online, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fascism. Accessed 28 February 2020.

How do I distinguish between these 2 sources while making in-text citations?

Answer (score 1):

(I have a very similar answer [but not the same] to this for [a similar question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/54143/mla-in-text-citations-for-websites/54154#54154).)

All of the examples in this answer are taken directly from [this link.](https://www.scribbr.com/mla/website-citation/#:%7E:text=An%20MLA%20website%20citation%20includes,title%20of%20the%20page%20instead) and [this link](https://www.scribbr.com/mla/journal-citation/).

My answer:

**You would just make two separate citations because you are citing two *separate* articles. However, you should still follow the same format for each of the website citations.**

If each of the articles has a date but no author, follow this citation:

**MLA website citation with no author**

Format: “Title of Article.” Website Name, Day Month Year, URL.
Works Cited entry: “US Election 2020: A Guide to the Final Presidential Debate.” BBC News, 21 Oct. 2020, [www.bbc.com/­news/­election-­us-­2020-­54620868](http://www.bbc.com/%C2%ADnews/%C2%ADelection-%C2%ADus-%C2%AD2020-%C2%AD54620868).
In-text citation: (“US Election 2020”)

If the articles do not have an author or date, follow this format:

**MLA website citation with no author or date**

Format: “Title of Article.” Website Name, URL. Accessed Day Month Year.
Works Cited entry: “Citing Sources and Referencing.” Scribbr, [www.scribbr.com/­category/­citing-­sources](http://www.scribbr.com/%C2%ADcategory/%C2%ADciting-%C2%ADsources). Accessed 16 July 2019.
In-text citation: (“Citing Sources”)

But, if the two articles are both written by the same author; you can follow this type of citation:

**MLA journal citation: 2 authors**

Works Cited: Eve, Martin Paul, and Joe Street. “The Silicon Valley Novel.” Literature & History, vol. 27, no. 1, May 2018, pp. 81-97, doi:10.1177/0306197318755680.
In-text citation: (Eve and Street 84)

For more information, check out [my answer here](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/54143/mla-in-text-citations-for-websites/54154#54154), [this article](https://www.scribbr.com/mla/website-citation/#:%7E:text=An%20MLA%20website%20citation%20includes,title%20of%20the%20page%20instead), and [this article.](https://www.scribbr.com/mla/journal-citation/)